# track which container was clicked on in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 containers and in each picture, when you click on which an icon appears. How to assign a value to each container, so that when you click it, you can change it too. Or how to track which container was clicked on

```
class _EditAccountScreenState extends State<EditAccountScreen> {
bool checkboxValue = false;
...
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () { 
                              setState(() {
                                checkboxValue = !checkboxValue;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                                child: Row(
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Container( 
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Image.asset('assets/images/telegram-512.png',fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                        Positioned(
                                          bottom: 0, right: 15, //give the values according to your requirement
                                          child: checkboxValue
                                              ? Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.green,
                                                      borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(100)
                                                    ),
                                                    child: Icon(
                                                      Icons.check,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      size: 15,
                                                    )
                                                  )
                                              : Container(),),],),),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Image.asset('assets/images/Viber-Logo.png',fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                        Positioned(
                                          bottom: 0, right: 15, //give the values according to your requirement
                                          child: checkboxValue
                                              ? Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.green,
                                                  borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(100)
                                              ),
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.check,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                size: 15,
                                              )
                                          )
                                              : Container(),),],),),
```

Comment: Wrap each container in separate `GestureDetector`

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Gesture Detector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to detect Taps on containers.**

Here is an example related to this:

```
    Container(
  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.lightbulb_outline,
          color: _lights ? Colors.yellow.shade600 : Colors.black,
          size: 60,
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _lights = true;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow.shade600,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('TURN LIGHTS ON'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All Make a `Integer` Variable and then set its value to `-1` by default

```
int selectedContainerIndex = -1;
```

**Now**, You Can `Wrap` each of your Container in seperate `GestureDetector`, and then on the `onTap` method you can set the `selectedContainerIndex` `value` of your `container` according to you.

*See the below `Code`*

```
   Stack(
      children: [
        //First Container
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            selectedContainerIndex = 0;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: new Container(),
        ),
        //Second Container
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            selectedContainerIndex = 1;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: new Container(),
        ),
        //Third Container
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            selectedContainerIndex = 2;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: new Container(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

*Now To know which `Container` was tapped you can always use the `selectedContainerIndex` Value*

```
print(selectedContainerIndex);
```

**NOTE**: If your `containers` are more in numbers say 4 or 5, then I would recommend you to use *good practice* and show those using some `dynamic` `listview builder`, instead of hardcoding them each.

Comment: how can i implement dynamically? coz i have 26 length of container